# How to sort a queue using a temporary stack?

Tags: algorithms, sorting, space-complexity, stacks, queues

Suppose we have N natural numbers in a queue. ex queue = [3, 14, 1, 20] and an empty stack

We are allowed to make only two actions:

1. Action "x": Dequeue an element from the queue and push it to the stack.
2. Action "o": Pop an element from the stack and enqueue it in the queue.

In the above example, the following actions sort the queue in ascending order:

Actions: "xxoxooxxoo"

ex.

- queue: 3, 14, 1, 20  stack:
- x
- queue: 14, 1, 20     stack: 3
- x
- queue: 1, 20         stack: 14, 3
- o
- queue: 1, 20, 14     stack: 3
- x
- queue: 20, 14        stack: 1, 3
- o
- queue: 20, 14, 1     stack: 3
- o
- queue: 20, 14, 1, 3  stack:
- x
- queue: 14, 1, 3      stack: 20
- x
- queue: 1, 3          stack: 14, 20
- o
- queue: 1, 3, 14      stack: 20
- o
- queue: 1, 3, 14, 20  stack:

and the queue is sorted.

Any idea how can I solve this problem with the **minimum** number of actions?

**[EDIT]**

Actually, it should be with a minimum number of steps, as there is a dummy solution:

You can just rotate the queue by actions: "xo" (move the first number to the end of the queue) and when you reach the largest number, push it to the stack. Repeat this process until the queue is empty. The stack now contains all the numbers with the top being the smallest number. So you just push them out one by one and you have a sorted queue.

Comment: What running time are you aiming for?

Comment: @Steven Could be done in O(N^2) or pseudo polynomial (nW) with dynamic programming ? (not sure if it can be done faster)

Comment: What is $W\phantom{}$?

Comment: @Steven W is the largest number. I don't know if that matters, but maybe there is an algorithm that takes into account which is the largest number of the queue, like Knapsack's complexity

Comment: @Throckmorton As is said, I don't think it can be done in less than n^2. Also, I don't get your point. If it is in reverse order, it just needs N pushes to stack and then N pops. ex: queue = [3, 2, 1], actions = "xxxooo" or even "xxoo"

Comment: What about the case for a queue which alternate increasing and decreasing sorted? For example [1,3,5,7,9,8,6,4,2]

Comment: Not a full solution, just a way to think about it: Call a state in which (a) the stack is empty and (b) we can reach the target sorted state in exactly $2N$ moves *1-easy*. If a state consists of 1 or more blocks in the queue, each of which consists of a nonincreasing segment followed by a nondecreasing segment, and such that $\max(B_i) \le \min(B_{i+1})$ for each block $B_i$, then the state is 1-easy (but note this does not exhaust the 1-easy states, so a better characterisation is needed). Call a state in which (a) the stack is empty and (b) we can reach an $i$-easy state *$(i+1)$-easy*.

Comment: Related to Knuth's concept of stack-sortability. [Sorting using Networks of Queues and Stacks (Tarjan, 1972)](https://dl.acm.org/doi/10.1145/321694.321704) might be helpful, though from looking at just the first page it seems concerned only with *whether* a sequence can be sorted in an acyclic network, rather than how efficiently a given sequence can be sorted.

Comment: Can you tell us where you encountered this task?  What's the context or motivation?

Comment: @D.W. It is an assignment in programming language course of my college.

Comment: Cross-posted: https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/140813/755, https://stackoverflow.com/q/67754647/781723.  Please [do not post the same question on multiple sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068).